# Cypress - use environment variables for various languages

Tags: ui-automation, cypress

I want to use Cypress environment variables to force browser to use different languages.

Here's what my example cypress.json looks like:

```
{
"env":{
    "baseUrl": "localhost",
    "language": {
        "en": "5.44.16.0",
        "se": "31.211.192.0"
    },
}
}
```

I tried this:

```
const market = Cypress.env(language.se) // se here is just an example, I want it to be dynamic
cy.server({
            onAnyRequest: function (route, proxy) {
                proxy.xhr.setRequestHeader(
                    "x-forwarded-for",
                    market
                );
            },
        });
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseUrl'))
```

But it didn't work.

What I want to achieve is to be able to execute Cypress with forcing the language from the command line like so:

```
cypress run --env language=se
```

Where 'se' stores the IP value from the cypress.json file
I'm new to Cypress so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have updated my answer with `npm run` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you need to read the 'ip' from the environment variable is wrong.

In `package.json` scripts:

```
  "test": "cypress run",
```

Refer: [How to run commands](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#How-to-run-commands)

> When calling a command using npm run, you need to pass the command’s arguments using the -- string.

`npm` command: `npm run test-local -- --env language=se`

`direct cypress command`: `cypress run --env language=se`

In `config.json`:

```
{
  "env":{
    "baseUrl": "localhost",
    "ip": {
        "en": "5.44.16.0",
        "se": "31.211.192.0"
    }
  }
}
```

In `Test` spec:

```
const language = Cypress.env('language');
const market = Cypress.env('ip')[language] // se here is just an example, I want it to be dynamic
cy.log(`All: ${JSON.stringify(Cypress.env('ip'))}`);
cy.server({
    onAnyRequest: function (route, proxy) {
        cy.log(`For language: ${language} => ${market}`);
        proxy.xhr.setRequestHeader(
            "x-forwarded-for",
            market
        );
    },
});
cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseUrl'))
```

[image: screenshot]

Note: I used `cypress open --env language=se` for the screenshot

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Unfortunately, It didn't work for me - I get:

For language: undefined => undefined https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5CvP.png

Comment: Are you setting the env variables using `npm run {cypress-script} --env language=se`?

Comment: I'm using `npm run cypress open --env language=en`
Which version of Cypress did you use to make it work?

Comment: Nevermind the version. I've just updated to most recent 4.8.0 and got the same result.

Comment: @mariobrosbb: Version is not the problem....the way your npm script is set...and you are executing the `npm run` has issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I'm facing a different problem with CORS but the language variable is set

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Thank you :) You can find it under this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62513920/cors-policy-error-when-trying-to-setrequestheader-in-cypress-test 
No one has posted any answers there yet